# MariaDB fulltext search with special chars and "word starts with"

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb, fulltext-index

I can do a MariaDB fulltext query which searches for the word beginning like this:

```
select * from mytable
where match(mycol) against ('+test*' in boolean mode)>0.0;
```

This finds words like "test", "tester", "testing".

If my search string contains special characters, I can put the search string in quotes:

```
select * from mytable
where match(mycol) against ('+"test-server"' in boolean mode)>0.0;
```

This will find all rows which contain the string `test-server`.

But it seems I cannot combine both:

```
select * from mytable
where match(mycol) against ('+"test-serv"*' in boolean mode)>0.0;
```

This results in an error:

```
Error: (conn:7) syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
```

Placing the ´*´ in the quoted string will return no results (as expected):

```
select * from mytable
where match(mycol) against ('+"test-serv*"' in boolean mode)>0.0;
```

Does anybody know whether this is a limitation of MariaDB? Or a bug?

My MariaDB version is 10.0.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE MATCH(mycol) AGAINST('+test +serv*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND mycol LIKE '%test_serv%'
```

The `MATCH` will find the desired rows plus some that are not desired.  *Then* the `LIKE` will filter out the duds.  Since the `LIKE` is being applied to only some rows, its slowness is masked.

(Granted, this does not work in all cases.  And it requires some manual manipulation.)

`d'Artagnan` - Use

```
WHERE MATCH(mycol) AGAINST("+Arta*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND mycol LIKE '%d\'Artagnan%'
```

Note that I used the suitable escaping for getting the apostrophe into the `LIKE` string.

So, the algorithm for *your* code goes something like:

1. Break the string into "words" the same way `FULLTEXT` would.
2. Toss any strings that are too short.
3. If no words are left, then you cannot use `FULLTEXT` and are stuck with a slow `LIKE`.
4. Stick `*` after the last word (or each word?).
5. Build the `AGAINST` with those word(s).
6. Add on `AND LIKE '%...%'` with the original phrase, suitably escaped.

Comment: Thanks, this will help for the "-" issue.

But this is a general problem: for example searching for "d'Artagnan": if the string "d'Arta" is entered, I cannot perform a search like this: 

`match (mycol) against (+"d'Arta"* in boolean mode) > 0.0`

Do you know of any doc/best pratice guide on how to handle those special chars?

Comment: @wknauf - I responded in my Answer.

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, I applied your suggestion to our code, and it works. Seems this is the "official" way to solve it ;-). Many thanks!